# How can I Violate Encapsulation property?

Tags: c++

How can I Violate Encapsulation property without having a compile time error? (in C++)

just so curious..

This was actually a question asked by one of my professor.. Please don't misunderstand. 
This was asked when we had a discussion over compiler error's

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Curiosity killed the cat you know...

Comment: I don't think this deserves a -1. +1 to remove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#define private public
#define protected public
#define class struct
```

There you go :-)

Comment: `template <class T> T youBrokeIt(const T& x) { return x; }`

Comment: @ega: Actually, that was intended as a joke. Why would anyone WANT to do this? Encapsulation is a good thing! If you really need to touch private parts, then your design is flawed, and you must refactor.

Comment: I meant it was an awesome joke! I would not even _dream_ to define private as public.

Comment: Ooh, you win it. A proper manifestation of evil if I've ever seen one.   Except...what about protected? :)

Comment: Ok.  Now we need to burn it with fire.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that by "violating encapsulation" you mean "accessing private members from outside a class".

The only way to do this "legally" that I know is using [friend classes / methods](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html).

However, in order to use them you will need to modify the class which has private members - at which point it might be simpler to just redefine some methods from `private` to `protected` or `public`, depending on the case.

Comment: friends do not break encapsulation, because you get to choose who your friends are. It's not like somebody could become your friend without your consent.

Comment: please see my first phrase - I'm defining "encapsulation" as "not being able to access private members from outside". It is not a "standard" or "complete" definition, but I suspect it is the one the OP is using on his question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to*.  Encapsulation is a feature of C++.

**unless you do something dark, evil, and magic.*

Comment: See [FredOverflow's answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002101/how-can-i-violate-encapsulation-property/3004223#3004223)  His is the manifestation of this evil. :)

Comment: Also, see [evil: adj. (from the Jargon file.)](http://catb.org/jargon/html/E/evil.html)

Answer (score 1):

You change the headers defining the classes in question to make the desired members public. In other words, you remove the encapsulation. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Design a mirror class that has the same members as the class you are trying to access the nonpublic members of and hardcast an object of said class to the mirror class.

```
class original
{
  private: int x,y,z;
  public: int dosomething();
};

class mirror
{
  public: int x,y,z;
};

int main()
{
  original *o = new original;
  mirror *m = (mirror*)o;
  m->x = 10;
}
```

this of course is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an evil c++ function that accesses private properties of a C++ class/C struct
as long as you know the memory layout of the struct or class0

```cpp
template<class V,class T>
void accessClassProperty(T* object,V* outValue,int offset){
   char* buf = (char*)object;
   V value = *((V*)&buf[offset]);
   *outValue = value;
}
```